# How can I use the row number in an Excel chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have an Excel table which is simply one column of dates. Each date has a distinct value, and they are already sorted. Something like:

> 5/29/2011
>   6/21/2011
>   6/26/2011
>   7/1/2011
>   7/3/2011
>   ...

I would like to produce a chart from this where the X axis is time and the Y axis is the row count for that time, like this:

[image: Chart example]

I can do this by introducing a new column with a value of `=Row()` and charting both columns, but this seems silly and inelegant. Can Excel plot this chart without me going through this additional hoop?

Comment: Yes, but Excel IS silly and inelegant. That's why so many of us enjoy bending it to our needs, while so many others bail for a non-silly, elegant solution like R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a built-in way do accomplish this task in Excel without using an additional column, using a feature called Named Ranges.

This example assumes that the dates are entered into cells `A1:A5`.

On the Formulas tab, choose Name Manager. Choose "New" to create a new name. Choose a name for the name, such as `rows`. Under "Refers to", enter the formula `=ROW(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5)` (this assumes that your sheet is called `Sheet1`). This formula should be extended past row 5 depending on how many dates you have.

[image: Edit Name]

Then, right-click on your chart, and choose Select Data. Edit the data series. Under "Series values", enter `=Sheet1!rows`, replacing `rows` with whatever you named the name before.

[image: Edit series]

Click OK twice, and the Y axis of your chart should now show the row numbers.

[image: Chart]

Answer (score 1):

Named Ranges are the way to go for your solution.  However, since you prefer something more elegant, I would use ranges for both your data and your axis labels, and make sure that they expand as you add data.

So, create a Named Range called Data, using the formula

`=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,0,0,COUNT(Sheet1!$A:$A),)`

Then, create a Named Range called Labels, using the formula

`=ROW(OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,0,0,COUNT(Sheet1!$A:$A),))`

These formulas will count your cells and add the data to both your chart and it's axis labels.  *ASSUMING that you start in Row 1 and don't have any gaps (blanks) in your data.*